# Bootstrap issue with float/container classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, css-float, internet-explorer-10

I am experiencing an issue with bootstrap in IE. It relates to the `.pull-right` class with just floats the `<div>` to the right.

This is a visual demonstation:

`Chrome 28`
[image]

`IE10`
[image]

The menu is construted using KendoUI and my site uses Bootstrap v.2.3.2 RC2. I am not aware of any compatibility issues with IE10. This issue does NOT present itself with IE9 or below though which is strange.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="main-ui-nav">
    <div class="container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    Customer
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="main-customer.php">Customer Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    Products
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="main-products.php">View Products</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    Sites
                    <ul>
                        <li>Add Site</li>
                        <li><a href="main-sites.php">View Registered Sites</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li>
                    Payments
                    <ul>
                        <li>Invoices</li>
                        <li>Agreements</li>
                        <li>History</li>
                        <li>Oustanding</li>
                        <li>Statements</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    

                <li>
                    Notes
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="create-note.php">Create Note</a></li>
                        <li>Amend</li>
                        <li><a href="main-notes.php">View</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    

                <li class="pull-right">
                    Session Options
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="includes/account/dectivate-account.inc.php">Exit Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="pull-right">Creation Options
                    <ul>
                        <li>Create Payment</li>
                        <li><a href="create-note.php">Create Note</a></li>
                        <li>Create Invoice</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

---

JS FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/davcpas123/QFdTN/8/embedded/result/

Comment: where is your css? can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due the KendoUI overriding the standard `.clearfix` classes.

To fix this I added :

```
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

to my `ui-full.css` file.